# Generate argparsers with behavior like apt-get install

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I read all the documentation about argparsers in python and I'm trying to make subparsers and mutual exclusions parsers but I can't achieve a similar behavior as typical "sudo apt-get install".

I want to pass the argument get alogn with suffix -info or -reverse and followed by subcommand fodder and/or dtype and the number for fodder or dtype to run proper action if is used get-info or get-reverse.

E.g.

```
~: python calculator.py get-info fodder 1000 => return a calculation
~: python calculator.py get-reverse fodder 1000 => return a invert calculation
~: python calculator.py get => displays get info (showing get-info... get-reverse)
```

I thing there is a way to do this with the methods of argparse Objects but I do not achieve to find the way to do it.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Defense Calculator')
    parse.add_argument('-f', '--fdu', type=int, default=1000, help='Fodder units')
    parse.add_argument('-p', '--profile', type=str, default="BigGunsMLG", help='Fodder units')
    parse.add_argument('-i', '--info', action="store_true", help='Print Defense Profiles lists')

    # create the top-level parser
    subparsers = parse.add_subparsers(help='getter-command help')

    # create the parser for the "foo" command
    parser_get = subparsers.add_parser('get', help='Require info of a Defense Profile')
    p_get_excluders = parser_get.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    p_get_excluders.add_argument('-info', action='store_true', help='Returning info elements by fdu')
    p_get_excluders.add_argument('-reverse', action='store_true', help='Returning fdus by element')
    parser_get.add_argument('fodder', type=int, default=1000, help='Fodder units')
    parser_get.add_argument('dtype', '--dtype', type=str, default='RL', help='Type of element to get info')
```

Comment: Do you really need `argparse`? Did you look at [click](https://github.com/pallets/click)? I highly recommend it. As for 'standartness' - it's used in pip.

Comment: What's wrong with `add_parser('get-info')` then `add_parser('get-reverse')` and finally `add_parser('get')`? Note that when implementing these 3 you can just implement a single function that has two parameters `info` and `reverse` that are `True/False` and tell the function what it should display/do. You don't need any mutually exclusive group in this way

Comment: When debugging `argparse` code, it's useful to `print(sys.argv)` and `print(args)`.  That way you see what the parser has to work with, and what it produced - in the rawest form.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're asking is for a way to have certain arguments separated by a dash instead of a space. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Would you be able to accomplish what you want with an argument called "get-info" and one called "get-reverse"? What does separating the word "get" out accomplish? Is it in hopes that you can plug other words (like set maybe?) in there and mix and match them?

APT (https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) is Debian's package manager. apt-get (https://wiki.debian.org/apt-get) is a command-line interface for it. "-get" is part of the command, not an argument being given to it. Its arguments are still parsed with spaces in between.

The shell (eg. Bash https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html) is what is parsing through the spaces between the parameters when you execute a program. It takes each word after the first (which is the name of the executable), separated by spaces, and puts them into an array of strings called the environment. Your program is receiving that array of strings and does not process the spaces between arguments or even see the spaces. They're already separated by the time it sees it.

I know I didn't quite answer your question, and maybe there is a simpler answer I don't know about. One idea I have would be to do some sort of pre-processing on your arguments before you send them to argparse. For example, you could loop through each argument and check for strings that begin with "get-" and if it does, do something to it at that level. I hope you found any of this helpful!

**Edit/More info:** (after reading your comment)

When your Python program is launched, the arguments have already been sorted into an array of strings. argparse is programmed to understand this array of strings. It is not able to break these strings up to my knowledge. If you're only planning on having these three options: get, get-info, and get-reverse, making each one of them its own argument might be the most pragmatic option. If that's too brute force for you and/or you're planning on adding more options, we need to think of ways of mutating the arguments between the point the program is run and the point that argparse reads them. argparse doesn't do what you want, so we have to take what you do want and change it into something that argparse actually accepts.

Here's an option: You can make it so that argparse works as you want it to for `calculator.py get`, `calculator.py get -info`, and `calculator.py get -reverse` with those extra spaces in there that you don't want. When the program is launched, the first thing it does is search for strings like `get-info` or `get-reverse` and changes them into 2 different strings, essentially adding a space between them that the user never typed. Then let argparse do its thing. Even though the user typed "get-info", argparse will interpret it as though they have typed "get -info" because you processed the text yourself between launching the program and calling argparse.

Comment: No, It's only the usage. I have the program .py so I would like to call it with commands by this way. myprogram.py get to display get commands like get-info and get-reverse and then call the program with those ones. myprogram.py get-info fodder 1000 and the program return a table with calcs results for a fodder param == 1000

Comment: Creating one argument like `parse.add_argument('get-info', ...` and one like `parse.add_argument('get-reverse', ...` should add the functionality you're describing as I'm understanding it. You can add another argument just called 'get' with `parse.add_argument('get', ...` that prints out a list of the get options you've created.

Comment: Yes, It's just what I'm doing now. There is some issue like avoid the use of both commands together. I'm thinking about it. Also I'm studing the option of use click like Alex Yu said.